# Python import issue with more than one folders

Tags: python, import

I'm continously struggling with python imports... I like the language but the importing mechanism makes me crazy. My time of coding spent to debugging why import is not working?!?!

Is it only me who is struggling with it?

Here is my latest problem:

folder structure (src folder):

```
 .:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 14:33 private
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 14:36 public
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 22 Dec 22 14:54 __init__.py

./private:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 14:51 models
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 15:52 utils
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 76 Dec 25 12:05 __init__.py

./private/models:
total 16
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 14:51 environment
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 28 Dec 25 12:04 __init__.py

./private/models/environment:
total 32
drwxr-xr-x 1 xy None  0 Dec 22 14:51 territories
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 47 Dec 22 17:08 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 88 Dec 22 18:02 ship.py

./private/models/environment/territories:
total 64
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 393 Dec 22 16:22 territory.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 115 Dec 22 16:26 own.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None  69 Dec 22 18:07 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 408 Dec 25 12:25 location.py

./private/utils:
total 32
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None  20 Dec 22 15:58 __init__.py
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 182 Dec 22 16:00 utils.py

./public:
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 xy None 0 Dec 22 14:36 index.py
```

I'm using python 3.4. My question is that, how can I import private.models.environment.ship in location.py.

I tried with this:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__)).split('src')[0], 'src'))
import private.models as models
```

but I'm getting the error message "no such module models"...annoying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If location.py is only a module (you can't use it as main program), your problem is solved with relative imports: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/

In location.py you can write

```
from .. import ship
```

And that's it!

Comment: thanks, I read the whole pep, and clarified me quite lot of things about imports. I hope from now on I won't have issues regarding importing python modules. That's a quite good summary.